The validity of the reasoning in Halting Theorem
Here is an example of the Halting Theorem from Wikipedia (Halting Problem)

Christopher Strachey outlined a proof by contradiction that the
halting problem is not solvable.The proof proceeds as
follows: Suppose that there exists a total computable function halts(f)
that returns true if the subroutine f halts (when run with no inputs)
and returns false otherwise. Now consider the following subroutine:
def g():     
   if halts(g):
       loop_forever()


halts(g) must either return true or false, because halts was assumed
to be total. If halts(g) returns true, then g will call loop_forever
and never halt, which is a contradiction. If halts(g) returns false,
then g will halt, because it will not call loop_forever; this is also
a contradiction. Overall, g does the opposite of what halts says g
should do, so halts(g) can not return a truth value that is consistent
with whether g halts. Therefore, the initial assumption that halts is
a total computable function must be false.

Question: When we use 'g' as input in the 'halts' algorithm, we already use the output of 'halts' with 'g'.
But this output is the result of what we are doing.
Let's call 'A' the result of the first pass of 'g' in 'halts' and 'B' the result of the second pass of 'g' in halts. B is an inference from A.
But 'B' is different from 'A'.
So we need to replace 'A' with 'B' and so on.
In a syllogism, we cannot use the conclusion in the premises because it would result in us proving the conclusion by the conclusion.
So I don't understand how the 'halting theorem' can be valid reasoning.
Can someone explain where is my error?
I'd learn the topic in Graham Priest's Very short introduction to logic in chapter 14. He uses the program who decides if a program will stop or not. A(x, x) when x is the code number of the program T who inverts the output of A. A calls the program T and inputs in T the code of T itself.
We assume that A(x, x) shows that T doesn't finish with an endless loop. So, following the definition of T, it will finish with an endless loop. This demonstrates that A failed to give a true result for T with input T.
But by definition, T jumps over the result of A. So, T doesn't belong to the world examined by A (but perhaps to a Metalanguage). T "is waiting" the result of A and says something. Therefore, we have disqualified A through a program which is not in the scope of A. I don't understand why is it not a fallacious reasoning.
Maybe that A is fit for programs that don't jump over it. T leads in an endless reasoning and there will be a need to pass it again and again to reach his result. But by definition A gives a definitive result. So T enter a bug in A. T is made to demonstrate that A reached necessarily the half of the way. This fact demonstrates that T isn't a program.
Note: @Mauro Allegranza in his comment and one of the answers (@Jordan Paillette) seem to say that T is not analyzable. And so A failed in his duty. But I feel that the problem is inherent to the fallacious nature of T.

"Suppose that there exists a total computable function halts( )". This is the assumption: the function receives as input the "description" (encoded in some way) of function f and gives as output... Then define a program (subroutine, function) g as above: this is a good description and thus we can encode it and use it as input to the halts(_) function to compute halts(g).

The input to the program g is not the output from g but the text of g itself. A program is just a string of characters. So if the halting problem was solvable, a program could read in its own text, determine whether it halts or not, and then halt if and only if it determines that it does not halt, which would be a contradiction.

See also The Unsolvability of the Halting Problem.

Well, go on to the next section in the Wikipedia article, "sketch of rigorous proof." Basically everything is a function of integer parameters, so there's no abstract recursion involved; halts(g) is really shorthand for halts(n, n) where n is a particular number assigned to g.

@causative I know it. So what?

@kouty So halts(n, n) doesn't "wait" for g or do a "pass" or a "second pass" over g. halts(n, n) is just a function of two integers.

@causative if so, it's as twice ~. To make twice g for every program return the same result as without g.

I see that two persons voted to close the question because it's off topic. I will be happy to edit following recommendations.

@MauroALLEGRANZA and thus we can encode it and use it as input to the halts(_) function to compute  but what is this halt(_)?

Have you tried actually expressing this as a syllogism? I don't think you can. One of the reasons that syllogistic is no longer in use is because it can't handle mathematical reasoning.

The mathematical Theory of Computation "reduces" problems to numerical ones: the model of computation is based on implementing algorithms as fucntions that receive number as input and produces as result (if any) a number. This is exactly waht electronic computers do. Thus, an "universal computer" (see Turing) is a machine that receives as input a big number "encoding" the description o a program (function), decode it (this is what comilers do) and run it to compute the result. 1/2

Thus, assuming that the program halt( ) exists, we write the simple program g( ) above, encode it (the result will be a number g) and provides the corresponding coding number to the program halt( ) itself, asking it to compute the output halt(g) (if any). 2/2

@MauroALLEGRANZA I'm reading your links. Thanks so much. Se non capisco in inglese ci proverò alrimente

@MauroALLEGRANZA thanks. I have a book called Turing vision .

Other participants have already commented on the fact that in proofs (e.g. in Strachey's proof) of the Halting Problem, to compute the value halt(f()) of the hypothetical program halt() on a program f(), halt() does not take as input the 'result' of f(), but rather 'the' description of the program f(). This answers the main question asked by kouty.
That being clarified, the title of the post still implicitly raises the more general question of the validity of Strachey's proof by contradiction, a question which has not been fully tackled up to now on this thread. Personally, I feel that Scrachey's proof (see his referenced paper above) implicitly relies on another assumption (beside and under the assumption A: 'there exists of a program halt()'), namely (roughly speaking) B: 'g() is a well-defined, existing program'.
What is sure is that, assuming A, then given a program f(), we could construct another program f'() as follows:
def f'():
   if halt(f):
      loop_forever()

Scrachey's proof relies on the assertion B: 'there exists a fixed-point g() to the map f() --> f'()'. If this assertion B could be proved (by a detailed analysis of the encoding of programs into integers---mentioned by other participants on this thread---that would reveal the existence of a program g() such that g'()=g()), then Scrachey's proof would rely on a single assumption, A, and so the paradoxical behavior of g() could only come from A being false. However, if B is taken as another assumption, then the paradoxical behavior of g() could also result from the falsity of B; and since B only makes sense under assumption A, common mathematical practice would lead to rejecting B and not (yet) A. So the fact that Scrachey's argument does not discuss the status of assertion B (and that proving B is probably not so simple, if possible at all -- edit: it is, see below) is, in my opinion, a drawback of this argument.
Note that the sketch of a rigorous proof of the Halting Problem given on Wikipedia does not proceed along the lines of Scrachey's argument. Instead, roughly speaking, for each program f(), one constructs another well-defined program e_f(); then assuming A and taking f() = h() := halt(), one sees that e_h() has a paradoxical behavior, which implies that h() is not an existing program i.e. assumption A is false. This 'diagonal argument' avoids the problematic self-referencing present in Scrachey's argument.
Edit: Jade Vanadium's comments to this answer explain how one could prove assertion B (assuming A). Roughly speaking, denoting by G the mapping of programs f() --> f'(), then G itself is computable (i.e., implementable via a program), hence G can take G as input to output G. Jade Vanadium's comment explain more generally how self-reference can be performed into programs.
For more information, look about Kleene's recursion theorem and Rogers' fixed-point theorem.

In the meantime I think this answer hits exactly what's bothering me.  Hypothesis B, as you named it, is difficult to conceive due to the fact that the function g is located above the world of the function h.  I think we can say that it belongs to a metalanguage while h belongs to language.  The bias of passing the code of g into h (while g itself takes the code of g as input) is perhaps fallacious.

@kouty  To complement that, I have a gist with some formal analysis of the so called Grelling–Nelson Paradox  (The proofs especially are difficult to decipher if one doesn't know Coq, I should really expand it into an article: anyway even in the present form might add some elements to the technical consideration.)

@JulioDiEgidio I'm afraid it's hard to get. But I will follow my way how I'm able to do.

The proof by diagonalization in the Wikipedia article is understandable

@kouty  The Grelling–Nelson paradox in fact is the most elementary form of diagonalization.  My link to some formal details was mainly inspired by your mentioning language vs meta-language: we are not going meta, rather and crucially this is all (re-)constructed within the language of interest (under specific assumptions whose rationale may be meta, e.g. "extensionality", but anyway become concrete as axioms or definitions).

@JulioDiEgidio thanks so much I'll try to understand your script.

@kouty First thanks for adding a reference to Scrachey's paper to my answer! As for your comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that g and h belong to different worlds/languages. For instance, in my definition of f', replace halt by not_halt; the new construct has a fix point. This shows that there is a real possibility for Scrachey's g to exist as a program (cf. Gödel's sentence). However, Scrachey's argument is a Russell-like paradox, and the reason for such paradoxes has often precisely been understood as the fact that one mistakenly considers an object which is out of the domain of discourse.

@JordanPayette Thanks so much for your expertise.

Assumption B is a mathematical theorem, so @kouty you could ask about B on Math SE and get some good answers. In short, you can explicitly construct a program execute which obeys the property that, for any (encoding of a) computer program f and any input x, we have execute(f,x) = f(x). This is a relatively standard theorem about computability theory, related to the existence of a Universal Turing Machine. We can then implement something like def G(f) : if halts(f): loopforever(), followed by def g() : execute(G,G).

typo I made: in the definition of G, we should have halts(f[f]), where f[f] is the computer program which simply returns the value execute(f,f). Equivalently, f[f] is identical to f except modified so that the first input has been hard-coded to be f. Given the program f, constructing the program f[f] is simple string manipulation which roughly doubles the length of the program f, so there is no chance of G failing to construct f[f].

@JadeVanadium (and @kouty) Interesting: so if I understand your comments, you take G to be the program/algorithm implementing my map f() --> f'()? To be sure I understand, please allow me to be pedantic: let h(x,i) be a total function on pairs of integers such that h(x,i)=1 if x=[X] is the Gödel number of a program X and X halts on input i, and h(x,i)=0 otherwise. Set def G(x): if h(x,x)=1: loopforever(); else: 0. Assuming h is a program, this defines a program G, to which corresponds the Gödel number [G]. Then considering G([G]) leads to the paradox. Is this the argument you meant? Thanks!

@JordanPayette That is equivalent for the purpose of analyzing the halting problem, though I hoped to clarify how to implement self-referencing programs in general. Given any function f(x,p) encoded by the program P, define g(x)=f(x,P) so that g is given a copy of the code of f. Whenever we need g to call itself recursively, e.g. if we need g(z) for some local variable z, we implement execute(p, (z,p)) at the appropriate location in the code P. Since g assigns p=P, that instruction will produce f(z,P), which is exactly g(z). If you want more clarification, you can ping me in chat

If I understand you correctly you seem to have a problem with using halts(g) twice in that scenario, that is once in asking whether or not g halts and once again inside g().
Though as lots of the comments tried to explain, though I'm not sure that has gotten across, you don't actually have to compute g in order to determine halts(g).
So technically the text of the function g is what is given as input to halts(). Or if you want to get even more technical you could take the characters and compute them to ascii so d = 100(dez) = 01100100(bin), e = 101 = 01100101, ... and then you concatenate them all together so 0110010001100101... and if we ignore for a second that this would be too big for any real world data type we could interpret that as 1*1+0*2+1*4+0*8+0*16+1*32+ ... and you'd end up with a single number representing the entire program.
So theoretically the halts function could just be a long list where this index stores a True/False value. In reality it can't because the list would be finite while the number of possible programs is infinite, but the point is that there's no necessity to actually run the function itself to determine it's truth value. So maybe the halting program would search for a particular substring of an infinite loop or however else you would go about trying to implement it. Though as another example, testing the code by running the actual function within the halt function would be a horrible idea, as it would never return anything for a non-halting program, given that the program would trap the halting function in an infinite loop. And you can't tell the difference between a program that just runs very very very very long and one that runs forever.
Like that's the very idea of a halting program in the first place, to tell you that without actually running the code and waiting in the worst case forever.
Now g is a function without inputs and random bits, so it behaves the same in every run (so either it halts or it doesn't). So the halting function, if it exists, should be able to produce a definitive value for g. However whatever the definitive value produced for g actually ends up as, if you run g, NOT halts(g), g will do the opposite of what halts(g) has predicted it to do.
